# IP Rotation - Is it possible to add a vpn on a python script?

Tags: web-scraping, proxy, vpn

I'm diving into web scraping and I was looking to add an IP rotation to my python script using the request library. I also want to put this script in production thanks to AWS lambda function.

From what I've read there seem to be two solutions: either use a VPN or use proxy lists with solutions such as crawlera, proxy rotators or others. However the latest solution is too expensive for me.

I've done some research and the first solution (VPN) seems to be the best solution in my case but I didn't find how to implement it on a script, can anyone give me a hint please?

Thanks a lot :)

Comment: VPN will change the ip of your PC so you don't need to change anything in the script.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, do you know if it is possible to install a VPN on a server?

In order to put my code in production and still have IP rotation :)

Comment: Sure. Your VPN provider will give you instructions for that.